# Codeigniter database error on MX/loader.php line 99

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have recently copied a codeigniter website over to a new domain with a new database, at first the coding was set to the old db as it was a straight copy and all was running fine. I created a new DB and imported all tables from the old, then changed all the DB details in the config database file. I am confident all details are correct and I have set my new user to all privileges. But now my site fails with the following:

```
  Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: root/third_party/MX/Loader.php

Line Number: 99
```

Which looks like this in my MX/Loader.php file

/** Load the database drivers **/

```
public function database($params = '', $return = FALSE, $active_record = NULL) {

    if (class_exists('CI_DB', FALSE) AND $return == FALSE AND $active_record == NULL AND isset(CI::$APP->db) AND is_object(CI::$APP->db)) 
        return;

    require_once BASEPATH.'database/DB'.EXT;

    if ($return === TRUE) return DB($params, $active_record);

    **CI::$APP->db = DB($params, $active_record);**

    return CI::$APP->db;
}
```

Line 99 is highlighted with the ** at each end. I can't figure out where the issue is, I've searched the likely files and found nothing pointing to the old db or that looks like it's in need of pointing to the new. Any help greatly appreciated! Cheers.

Comment: I should probably add it's all the same hosting, root directory etc, simply trying to use one site code to help generate another

Comment: checke your application>config>database.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `database.php` in `config folder` and paste below code at the end and debug your database connection first...

```
  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($db['default']);
  echo '</pre>';

  echo 'Connecting to database: ' .$db['default']['database'];
  $dbh=mysql_connect
  (
    $db['default']['hostname'],
    $db['default']['username'],
    $db['default']['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ($db['default']['database']);

    echo '<br />   Connected OK:'  ;
    die( 'file: ' .__FILE__ . ' Line: ' .__LINE__);
```

Comment: Hi Praveen - is this after my conig settings or should I remove them first?

Comment: NO no leave them as they are and paste at the last of `database.php` :)

Comment: Ok I get a PHP error saying acces denied to my defined username @ localhost (using password:YES) - does that give any clues to the issue?

Comment: Then go to `$db['default']['password'] ` and leave its value blank as `$db['default']['password'] = '';` and you will be good to go.. and dont forgot to upvote and mark my answer... :)

Comment: hmm, doing that first generated a syntax error saying unexpected ';' so I reomved that and now getting same as before but with using password:NO - still doesn't seem to be working for me

Comment: What error do you get now and what is the value of `$db['default']['dbdriver']` ??

Comment: Error is   'A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Filename: config/database.php

Line Number: 77'

Comment: and dbdriver value is mysql

Comment: Same issue with root as username too, Message: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: @DMinch Are you on localhost or live server  ??

Comment: Yeah I have full access

Comment: then `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'ask to your hosting providers';$db['default']['username'] = 'your_login_username';$db['default']['password'] = 'your_login_password';$db['default']['database'] = 'your_database_name';` cant tell any further... :) hope this helps you...

Comment: Praveen works beautifully, I changed my password and not sure if that had anything to do with it but your code at the bottom then executed once I'd refilled all my details and once removed the site works great - thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Do the following Steps :

1) In config/config.php file => Set correct $config['base_url']
   e.g. $config['base_url'] = 'http://myprojectttt.com';

2) check case sensitivity for file, variable, database name etc.

3)Configure config/database.php file correctly

I had given my database.php file configuration for your reference

/******************* database configuration start ******************/

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
//if you are not using any other db server keep "localhost as it is" =>   this solved my problem

$db['default']['username'] = 'ranjit'; 
$db['default']['password'] = 'ranjit';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database_name';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli'; //change dbdriver to yours driver  eg.mysql
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

/******************* database configuration end ******************/

please comment if any changes required in this answer.

Thank you.